# Unsigned 32 bit integer modulo 90

Tags: integers

I need a fast way to evaluate modulo 90 of any unsigned 32 bit.
One way I am aware of is to represent 1/90 as 0.7111111111111 * 2^-6, then represent 0.7111111111111 as 3054198966 * 2^-32. Hence, if I multiply the input with 3054198966, take upper 32 bits with rounding and shift right by 6 bits, I get the result of input divided by 90. I then take the result, multiply by 90, and subtract that from the input.
This technique, which relies on MulHigh, is expensive - it costs 1 32bx32b-->64b multiplication, 1 32b multiplication and 1 subtraction.
I wander whether there is a cheaper way.

Comment: Is `x % 90` slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the C program below

```
unsigned int test(unsigned int x)
{
        return x % 90;
}
```

The code generated for this program with `cc -O2` (clang-800.0.38) is

```
movl    %edi, %eax
shrl    %eax
movl    $3054198967, %ecx
imulq   %rax, %rcx
shrq    $37, %rcx
imull   $90, %ecx, %eax
subl    %eax, %edi
movl    %edi, %eax
popq    %rbp
retq
```

which seems to agree with your technique, except that it uses $3054198967$ instead of $3054198966$.

Bottom line: Use `x % 90` and trust the compiler to generate efficient code.

Comment: See also https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/src/IntegerDivisionTable.cpp.